# Passing an array from a template to a helper function

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Using Ember, I'm attempting to pass an array from a template

```
{{segment-array images 5}}
```

to a helper function

```
export function segmentArray([array, itemsPerRow]) {

  /* Logic to create and a return multidimensional array */

}
```

I know `images` is being populated correctly as I can use the `{{#each}}` helper on it. However, `array` is being passed in as `"<(subclass of Ember.ArrayProxy):ember355>"` with no length or content.

How can I pass in, modify, and return an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ArrayProxy` *has* `length` and `content`, just don't use dot notation but Embers `.get()`:

```
Ember.get(array, 'length');
```

But if you want to simply loop you can use [`.forEach`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_forEach):

```
array.forEach((item, index) => {
  ...
});
```

also you can use the `for of` loop:

```
for (let item of array){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just tried using get, however, length returns 0 and content returns null. I'm at a complete and utter loss at how that could be possible.

Comment: Hm, then your array is not populated. How do you fetch it? Is it maybe an async relationship or something like that? A PromiseArray? Check if `.then()` is defined.

Comment: Aha! .then() is indeed defined! Is that just the way it works in Ember or is there a better way of working with arrays?

Comment: Maybe check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298989/ember-js-dynamic-model-requests)